# Transaction viewing changes to database rows made after it began

Tags: postgresql, go, transactions, isolation-level, go-gorm

I've discovered something I can't wrap my head around when working with Postgres and Go GORM.

In the following code snippet, I try and Find, Delete, and Create the same item, but in 2 different transactions, however I begin the second transaction and Find the item BEFORE committing the first transaction.

In the second transaction, something strange happens. When I call `t2.Delete()`, it doesn't Delete any rows. In the database, after calling `t1.Commit()`, the primary key of the item becomes `2`, but since it already got the old item, it Deletes for the primary key `1`.

**Why does transaction 2 see the new row, despite being created BEFORE committing the first?**

```golang
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localHost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=test password=postgres sslmode=disable")
defer db.Close()
db.DropTableIfExists(&Product{})
db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})
db.LogMode(true)

db.Create(&Product{Code: "A", Price: 1000})
// SQL: INSERT  INTO "products" ("code","price") VALUES ('A',1000) RETURNING "products"."id"

// Start transaction 1, find item, delete it
t1 := db.Begin()
product := &Product{}

err = t1.Find(product, "code = ?", "A").Error
// SQL: SELECT * FROM "products"  WHERE (code = 'A')

err = t1.Delete(product).Error
// SQL: DELETE FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."id" = 1

// Start transaction 2 and get item, before transaction 1 creates new item and commits
t2 := db.Begin()

product2 := &Product{}
err = t2.Find(product2, "code = ?", "A").Error
// SQL: SELECT * FROM "products"  WHERE (code = 'A')

err = t1.Create(&Product{Code: "A", Price: 3000}).Error
// SQL: INSERT  INTO "products" ("code","price") VALUES ('A',3000) RETURNING "products"."id"

err = t1.Commit().Error
// Database now contains

err = t2.Delete(product2).Error
// SQL: DELETE FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."id" = 1
// [0 rows affected or returned ]

err = t2.Save(&Product{Code: "A", Price: 4000}).Error
// SQL: INSERT  INTO "products" ("code","price") VALUES ('A',4000) RETURNING "products"."id"
// ERROR HERE: pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "products_code_key"

err = t2.Commit().Error
```

**Note:** GORM uses by default `Read Committed isolation level`. I'm aware of the integrity issues that this would cause, if it worked correctly. I'll instead be using `Serializable`, which would give an error on Commit, or would block on Get, if specified `"FOR UPDATE;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PostgreSQL [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html)

> Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. When a
>   transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (without a FOR
>   UPDATE/SHARE clause) sees only data committed before the query began;
>   it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during
>   query execution by concurrent transactions. In effect, a SELECT query
>   sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to
>   run.

...

> Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see different data,
>   even though they are within a single transaction, if other
>   transactions commit changes after the first SELECT starts and before
>   the second SELECT starts.

The second paragraph seems to sum up your situation. Any "SELECT" in `t2` that is started after `t1` is committed can see the updates applied by `t1`.